# Подсветка синтаксиса Html в приложение на Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. В данный момент я разрабатываю редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса на Anroid. Возникли проблемы при реализации подсветки синтаксиса на HTML. Можете ли посоветовать какие-нибудь ресурсы/книги для реализации подобно функционала? Текст подсвечиваю в элементе EditText, а для подсветки использую SpannableString, но не понимаю принципа по которому буду выбирать необходимые фрагменты для подсветки.

Comment: вот здесь есть посмотри, может решение какой подойдет.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсветка синтаксиса - совершенно нетривиальная задача. Я бы сравнил ее по объему с компиляцией. В принципе, для подсветки синтаксиса нужно выполнить почти то же самое, что и для компиляции кода - распарсить его. Есть в общем-то уже более-менее готовые библиотеки для подсветки кода. Найти их несложно. Попробуйте [эту](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/), например.
Вот [поисковый запрос](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20html%20syntax%20highlighter&es_th=1), которым я прользовался.